# Why when I have two mysqli queries one after another I can execute only the first one?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote the following php code:

```
if ($insert_client_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO client (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
    $insert_client_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password);
    // Execute the prepared query.
    if (! $insert_client_stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
    }

}
$client_id = $mysqli->insert_id;




if ($insert_client_details_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO client_addr (addr_id, client_id, client_name, contact_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
$insert_client_details_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $client_id, $_POST['company'], $_POST['contact']);
// Execute the prepared query.
if (! $insert_client_details_stmt->execute()) {
    header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
}

}

header('Location: ./register_success.php');
```

and after going through that code my browser redirects me to the page register_success.php, but in my database I have only new client, entry in client_addr is missing. What can cause this? Do I have to reset somehow the mysqli? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First, you're handling errors worst way ever. And thus **depriving yourself from getting useful error message** that could helped you. For the proper error handling in mysqli you have to get rid of all these useless if's and tell mysqli to throw exception in case of error.

Second, the error itself, is simple: you're passing three variables into second query while having four fields in the INSERT query. You have to take out addr_id and corresponding placeholder from the query

So, the code would be.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO client (username, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$client_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO client_addr (client_id, client_name, contact_name) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $client_id, $_POST['company'], $_POST['contact']);
$stmt->execute();

header('Location: ./register_success.php');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out! I'm just beginnig my adventures with php and I have no idea yet about error handling, could you briefly explain me and help me understand why it's the worst way ever above? Thanks! I'm asking because I did a fix as you suggested and removed the attribute and placeholder, but it still doesn't work..